# Additional include directory in Visual studio 2015 doesn't work

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, include

I was trying to re-use an available source code for my own project, it can be found here:
https://github.com/TadasBaltrusaitis/OpenFace
I tried compiling project FeatureExtraction of the original code, everything was fine. Then I created a new empty project and added the following #include:

```
#include "LandmarkCoreIncludes.h"

#include <Face_utils.h>
#include <FaceAnalyser.h>
#include <GazeEstimation.h>
```

These are exactly the same as in project FeatureExtraction in the provided source code. I've already changed the additional include directories in C/C++ general tab into:

```
$(SolutionDir)\lib\local\FaceAnalyser\include  
$(SolutionDir)\lib\local\LandmarkDetector\include
```

However, it still gave me "cannot open source file error".
Update: If I put the absolute path of the header file directly to the code it is OK, however if I put the absolute path to the Additional Include Directories, the error remained.

Comment: Isnt that include should be in quotes for the local headers `#include  "FaceAnalyser.h"` ?

Comment: That's what I thought, too but somehow it works in the original code and also the header files are not in same directory as the project files.

Answer (score 2):

Use `#include "header.h"` instead of the one with diamonds `(< and >)` which looks in another directory.

After that, check if the header files really are in these directories. If they are, you should check the `$(SolutionDir)` ( I don't use a `'\'` after the `$(SolutionDir)` but it may work out as well).

Try to locate and delete the `.suo` file and restart `VS`

Comment: Hi, thanks for comment. The header files are indeed in the designated folder.  I also tried removing the '\' after $(SolutionDir)$ but it still didn't work.  The restarting method after deleting .suo also didn't work.  The weird thing is that I copied same settings from the original project, which works just fine, but my new created project didn't.

Comment: I suppose you already tried the "turn it off and on again"-method? Just restart the machine, maybe something is messing with PATH. To what does your $(SolutionDir) evaluate? You can check this inside VS

Comment: @pyroshawn: "copying settings from original project" - do you mean exactly that? Or do you mean "copying settings from original **solution**"? Because two projects can share a single solution, and thus a single `$(SolutionDir)`, but two solutions won't share their `$(SolutionDir)`. That's pretty much the point of `$(SolutionDir)`.

Comment: I deleted the `.suo` file and restart `VS`, that works for me. Thank you. VS 2017 Community Version

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I had same "bug" as mentioned in this post here:
[Visual Studio does not honor include directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790632/visual-studio-does-not-honor-include-directories)
After having changed the Additional Include Directories for all platforms instead, the code was compiled without any errors.